# Formatting table and figure number and title separately

Tags: tables, captions

I'm submitting to a journal that requests tables and figures to be formatted in the following way:

1. The term FIGURE 1 or TABLE 1 (all caps, ideally) centered above the figure.
2. The table/figure title below the figure, without the table/figure number.

I am able to get requirement (2) to work by using the caption package and `\caption*{Table Title}` inside the tabular but below the table. But then there's no FIGURE #/TABLE # above the figure/table. I can't find anything that would allow me to have the FIGURE #/TABLE # all-caps and centered.

How can I format my figures and tables to these rather silly specifications? My apologies if I'm missing something super obvious, I have been looking for a while.

For example, using standard code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\caption{Figure Title} 
\includegraphics[width=.80\textwidth]{example.png} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Gets me

Figure 1. Figure Title

[Image]

and

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=.80\textwidth]{example.png} 
\caption*{Figure Title} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Gets me

[Image]

Figure Title

but I want:

FIGURE 1

[Image]

Figure Title

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you submits article to some journal there is high probability that this journal ha own template (`\documentclass{...}`) for article, where your problem had to be solved. Otherwise, please clarify your question with small, complete code, which show your problem. On this way is more easy to help you. On the first sight your problem is simple to solve (if it the example of your document is available).

Comment: Unfortunately the standard in my field is Word, and most journals don't have TeX templates, including this one. Here's the basic code I use:


`\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \caption{Figure Title.}
 \includegraphics[width=.80\textwidth]{example.png}
\end{figure}`


will give me:

Figure 1. Figure Title.
[Image here]

If I instead do:


`\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=.80\textwidth]{example.png}
\caption*{Figure Title.}
\end{figure}`



I get
[Image here]
Figure Title.

What I want is
FIGURE 1
[Image here]
Figure Title.

Comment: Please, edit your question and put this code (completed so, that it can be copied and complied) and explanation there. On this way more people will seen it and be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with two captions in your figure environment? (Not a rhetorical question — if that's the wrong thing to do, I'd like to know.)

**EDITED** to uppercase the caption label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{upper}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~#2}
\captionsetup{labelformat=upper}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \includegraphics[width=.80\textwidth]{example.png}
  \caption*{The first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \includegraphics[width=.80\textwidth]{example.png}
  \caption*{The second figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I swear this was the first thing I tried and it didn't work at all, but it definitely works! I must have done it wrong then. Thank you! The only piece left is capitalizing FIGURE.

Comment: I modified the above to uppercase the caption label automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the figure environment to typeset the number of the figure before the caption. Since, however, the figure number is increased in the caption macro, you have to first increase the respective counter, then typeset it, and then decrease it again. This solution only counts correctly if every `figure`-environment has a `\caption`.

Additionally, this sets all content within a figure centered, if you do not want this, put the `\centering` command in the redefinition in a group to keep its effects local.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Clear the label from the caption 
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

% store the old definitions of the figure environment
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\origendfigure\endfigure

\renewenvironment{figure}{%
  \addtocounter{figure}{1}%                       Increase the counter
  \origfigure%                                    Original figure environment
  \centering%                                     Center content 
  \uppercase{Figure~\thefigure}\\[\baselineskip]% Typeset figure number
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%                      Decrease counter                    
}{%
  \origendfigure
}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\begin{figure} 
  \includegraphics[width=.30\textwidth]{example-image} 
  \caption{foo} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} 
  \includegraphics[width=.30\textwidth]{example-image} 
  \caption{bar} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```